# facebook comments system for asp.net mvc 2 website

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-2, facebook-c#-sdk

I know this sort of question has probably been asked many times before, but I can't find an answer.

I have an asp.net mvc 2 website for which I've built a membership system based on the standard asp.net membership provider.
I would like to add to that website a comments system where users, in order to comment on a topic, will be able to log into their facebook account (from within my website), and then make the comment. The comment should be shown on my website of course, and also in their facebook account, on their wall, or something similar, with something like "user x posted a comment on website y".

So my question is how do I build a facebook based comment system for my asp.net mvc 2 website using facebook c# sdk, or any other way ?
Code samples or tutorial links would be great, thanks ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the new facebook comment social plugin

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a specific example-- but you're going to need to use the Facebook API to do OATH authentication. You'll end up getting an authtoken back that you can then associate with your ASP.NET membership provider user. There are other API calls which will then allow users to post from  your application to their walls and also allow your application to read from their walls. Of course the user will have to give your application the appropriate permissions. There are some libraries which will make your life easier so you don't have to write things from scratch.